# Do unbiased L2 consistent, consistent in probability, or almost sure consistent estimator have a asymptotic variance equal to rao-cramer or better?

Tags: consistency, cramer-rao

Does a L2 consistent, consistent in probability, or almost sure consistent estimator have a asymptotic variance equal to rao-cramer or better?

With almost-sure consistency, why doesn't the estimator have a variance lower than that of the Rao-Cramer lower bound?